# How to install Anaconda in oh my zsh

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, anaconda

I try to install Anaconda on my Mac
my shell is using oh my zsh now

when I install zsh Anaconda.sh, it returns this error

```
cannot execute native osx-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Darwin Roy-MacBook-Pro.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

but I can install it with bash Anaconda.sh, and it works well

how can I solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

The Anaconda installer is written in bash. You need to run `bash Anaconda.sh`, regardless of what shell you use. The only difference is that at the end, you'll need to add anaconda to your PATH in your zshrc rather than bashrc, which is what the installer will do.

Comment: Don't forget to 'restart' zsh `source ~/.zshrc`